# Smooth and not smooth surface parametrisation

Tags: calculus

Give an example of two parametrisations of the same surface, one which is smooth, one which is not.

Comment: What do you mean by a parametrization of a surface, say a map $f:[0,1]^2\to S$ which is surjective? Then take $S = [0,1]^2$ and consider $f_1 = \mathrm id$ and take $f_2$ to be any discountinuous rearrangement of the elements of $S$ you like.